# Python Flask - Login_user or @login_required not working

Tags: python, flask

So I've looked everywere and couldn't find an answer to this problem. Whenever I use the @login_required tag I'm still not able to access those urls even after logging in a user.

Here is my views.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from flask_login import login_required, current_user

views = Blueprint("views", __name__)

@views.route("/")
@login_required
def home():
print(current_user.is_authenticated)    
return render_template('home.html')
```

Here is my init file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path
from flask_login import LoginManager

db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"

def create_app():
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "helloworld"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
db.init_app(app)

from .views import views
from .auth import auth



app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix="/")
app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix="/")

from .models import User

create_database(app)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = "auth.login"
login_manager.init_app(app)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    User.query.get(int(id))

return app

def create_database(app):
if not path.exists("website/" + DB_NAME):
    db.create_all(app=app)
    print("created database")
```

and here is my app.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, flash, url_for, redirect
from . import db 
from .models import User
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, login_required, current_user
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

auth = Blueprint("auth", __name__)

@auth.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

if request.method == 'POST':

    username = request.form.get("username")
    password = request.form.get("password")

    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

    if user:
        if check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            flash('Logged In!')
            login_user(user, remember=True)
            
            return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
        else:
            flash("Password is incorrect", category='error')
    else:
        flash("Incorrect username", category='error')
return render_template('login.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

@auth.route("/sign-up", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sign_up():

if request.method == 'POST':
    
    username = request.form.get("username")
    password = request.form.get("password")

    username_exists = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    
    if username_exists:
        flash('Username is already in use', category='error')
    elif len(password) < 5:
        flash('Password is not secure', category='error')
    else:
        new_user = User(username=username, password=generate_password_hash(password, 
method="sha256"))
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
        login_user(new_user, remember=True)
        
        flash('User Created')
        return redirect(url_for('views.home'))

return render_template("sign-up.html")

@auth.route("/logout")

def logout():
     logout_user()
     return "logout"
```

Whenever I try logging a user in they are logged out by flask. The user was logged in for the GET method but not the POST method as shown below in my console when I print whether the user is authenticated.

127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2021 23:13:17] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
True
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2021 23:13:29] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 -
False
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2021 23:13:29] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Any help is greatly appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not regarding login.

The problem here is your settings.py where you might have added some default settings where flask checks for email_confirmation flag etc.

Find below the basic flask settings which are required to run your code please try this and start from there.

```
# Flask-User settings
USER_APP_NAME = "Flask-User Basic App"  # email templates and page footers
USER_ENABLE_EMAIL = True  # Enable email authentication
USER_ENABLE_USERNAME = False  # Disable username authentication
USER_EMAIL_SENDER_NAME = USER_APP_NAME
USER_EMAIL_SENDER_EMAIL = "noreply@example.com"
USER_LOGIN_URL = '/login'
USER_LOGOUT_URL = '/logout'
```